# Linking to a section of an Accordion from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter-Bootstrap 2.04, and I'm using the latest jQuery.
I'm trying to make a link that will go from one page to the page containing this accordion, and then activate the appropriate accordion section.
This is the accordion:

```
 <div class="accordion-group">
          <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a name="Alink1" class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
            <strong>Title</strong>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body in collapse" style="height: auto; ">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
             some random content
            <div>
          </div>
 </div>
 <div class="accordion-group">
          <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a name="Alink2" class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
            <strong>Title 2</strong>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse" style="height: 0px; ">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
             some random content 2
            <div>
          </div>
 </div>
```

This is the link:

```
  <a href="page.html/#Alink2">Link to some interesting stuff</a>
```

With linking to just a bit in the page works fine usually, do I need to use Javascript to activate it?

Comment: This doesn't work for me on the twitter bootstrap site with their example, so I am assuming it's not default functionality.

Comment: You need to have the correct jScript attached to the file, it works fine.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, you will need to manually activate it on page load.  Something like the following should work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  location.hash && $(location.hash + '.collapse').collapse('show');
});
```

Also, as @SaadImran pointed out, this assumes that you link to the collapsible element id (eg., `#collapseTwo`) rather than the name in the anchor (eg., `#Alink2`).

Comment: +1, You should point out that OP would need to use the link `page.html#collapseOne` instead of `page.html#Alink1`

Answer (score 8):

Thanks for your help.
I added functionality so that the code can open Accordions WITHIN Accordions:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if (location.hash){
    $(location.hash).collapse('show');
    $(location.hash).parents('.accordion-body').collapse('show');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the position of the accordion section. The following link opens the third accordion section on a twitter bootstrap (wordpress) accordion.

Link Example: http://www.zfp-bauwesen.de/leistungen/ubersicht#3

Javscript Code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

 if (window.location.hash) {
   var AccordionSectionNumber = window.location.hash.substring(1);
   AccordionBodyID = $(".accordion .accordion-group:nth-of-type(" + AccordionSectionNumber + ") .accordion-heading a").attr('href')
      if (! (typeof AccordionBodyID === "undefined")) {
        $(AccordionBodyID).collapse('show');
        return true;
      }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this:

```
<a href="page.html#Alink2">Link to some interesting stuff</a>
```

Comment: That links to the page, but not to the accordion section.