# Collapsible div - expand and collapse

Tags: html, css, collapsable

Help please!

I'm creating a FAQs webpage where theres approx 50 questions. Therefore, I'm using collapsible divs so that the page isn't too long. Below is the code I've used so far.

I'm wondering if its possible to have a hyperlink (e.g. /#question20) where I can jump to a particular div which is automatically expanded by clicking on the hyperlink?

Also, what would be the best way of creating expand all / collapse all buttons?

Thanks in advance!

```html
<div class="panel-group" style="width: 70%; float: right; min-width: 300px;">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title"><strong><a href="#collapse1" data-toggle="collapse">Question 1</a></strong></h3>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">Answer 1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title"><strong><a href="#collapse2" data-toggle="collapse">Question 2</a></strong></h3>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">Answer 2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The `<details>` element might work for you --> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details (I think Edge support is limited / nonexistent though)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linking to a section of an Accordion from another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008389/linking-to-a-section-of-an-accordion-from-another-page)

Answer (score 0):

With only html you can use `<details>` and `<summary>` tag
If you want use javascript, you should create a tag and add a **load** event listener to it.

in the function associated for that listener you can toggle a class called **hidden** or change directly the style, for example we change the style with a new class called **hidden** to the divs you can expand and hide:

change your **html** to add a new class to the hidden div:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title"><strong><a href="#collapse1" data-toggle="collapse">Question 1</a></strong></h3>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse hidden">
        <div class="panel-body">Answer 1</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title"><strong><a href="#collapse2" data-toggle="collapse">Question 2</a></strong></h3>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse hidden">
        <div class="panel-body">Answer 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

add a new **css** rule

```
.hidden {
            display: none;
}
```

and finally the **script**:

```
<script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function() {
            var expandLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.panel-heading .panel-title a ');

            for(var i = 0; i < expandLinks.length; i++) {
                expandLinks[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                    console.log(event.currentTarget);
                    var selector = event.currentTarget.getAttribute("href");
                    var answersDiv = document.querySelector(selector);
                    answersDiv.classList.toggle('hidden');
                });
            }
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any JavaScript, just the CSS `:target`.
Such element will also expand if someone opens your page navigating with an URI like `yourwebsite.com/qa.php#collapse2`

```css
.panel-collapse { display: none; }
.panel-collapse:target { display: block; }
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title"><strong><a href="#collapse1" data-toggle="collapse">Question 1</a></strong></h3>
  </div>
  <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">Answer 1</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title"><strong><a href="#collapse2" data-toggle="collapse">Question 2</a></strong></h3>
  </div>
  <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">Answer 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```